# jQuery slice backwards or select previous 5 siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm cycling through a series of divs so only 5 appear at a time by using the slice() method. After every 4th item, there's an ellipsis (...) link, which directly leads the user to the next set of 5 items. Here's how it would look with all showing rather than just the 5 in case you're confused.
< 1 2 3 4 … 5 6 7 8 … 9 10 11 12 … 13 14 15 16 >

When a user clicks on back arrow, I want the previous 5 divs to show. For example, if they are on the second set of 5 (div 5, 6, 7, 8, ...), clicking the back arrow would hide those and show the previous 5 (div 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). I don't think slice() works backwards, and prev() won't work since I don't know of a way to select the previous 5 siblings. Nth-child won't work either because I want to select the previous 5 and not just :nth-child(5n).

Any thoughts on how this can work? I'm stumped. I'm not a jQuery Jedi, but I'd say my current skill level is above beginner. I'm probably making the functionality way more complicated than it needs to be. I've made a fiddle showing what I have completed already.
https://jsfiddle.net/nehLuj98/

```
$(".btn-nav").slice(0,5).show();
$(".btn-ellipsis").each(function(){
    var goNum = $(this).prev(".btn-num");
    var num = Number(goNum.attr("id"));
    var currentNum = $(this).find(".current");
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".btn-num").hide().slice(num,(num+4)).show().next(".btn-ellipsis").show();
        $(this).next(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(".btn-num").hide().slice(num,(num+4)).show().next(".btn-ellipsis").show();
        goNum.add("#"+(num+1)+"").addClass("current");
    });
    $(".btn-prev").click(function(){
        //Here's where I'd like to add the functionality to show the previous 5 items
        //$(".btn-nav").add(".btn-ellipsis").hide();
    });
});
```

I am using AngularJS, so these numbers are created dynamically based on the .json file. Don't know if that's relevant or not. The ellipsis link is being inserted after every 4th numbered link because the amount of links can very. For the fiddle, I just added it to the html for simplicity's sake.

**TL;DR**
Is there a way to use jQuery's slice() method backwards or select the previous 5 siblings using a different method?

Comment: Off the top of my head without testing, using the code you already have, maybe something like:  `$(".btn-num").hide().slice((num-4),num).show()`  might need -5 and -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current code, you could do this:

```
$(".btn-prev").click(function(){
    if ($('.current').attr('id') === '1' || $('.current').attr('id') === '4')
    return;
  var currentElip = $('.btn-ellipsis:visible');
    if (!currentElip.length)
    currentElip = $('.btn-next');
  else
    currentElip.hide();
  var goNum = currentElip.prevAll('.btn-ellipsis').prev(".btn-num");
  var num = Number(goNum.attr("id"));
  $(".btn-num").hide().slice(num-4,(num)).show().next(".btn-ellipsis").show();
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $("#"+(num)).addClass("current");
});
```

Here is the fiddle with some comments:

https://jsfiddle.net/nehLuj98/10/